# usatilea.nextmp.net is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: magento-1.9, error, error-log, http-request, http-error-500

I just moved my site from local to live server it was working fine on local but as its moved over live start giving the error

```
is currently unable to handle this request.
```

This is the domain that i am using : http://usatilea.nextmp.net/

I have cleared all the cache by deleting the var/cache and also updated the secure and unsecure urls in database too.

Print Errors on front end and gives this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555 Stack trace: #0 /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #1 /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() #2 /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') #3 /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') #4 /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction() #5 /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mag in /chroot/home/usatilea/usatileandmarble.net/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 555
```

Server Error log also not have any error in it. check the following image:
[image]

Please help to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is **php version** issue your current **magento version** is not compatible with php version.

**solution 1** install php 5.6

**solution 2** upgrade magento version